# How to update an multi-dimensional array based on its original array without overriding current array items?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Given $duplicateArray which is copy of $originalArray.
In $duplicateArray - only 'dynamic' values are allowed to change by user.

If the $originalArray changes , ie-

- New Section is added
- New Key is added to existing section
- Static/dynamic value is changed

How can the $duplicateArray array be changed to only

- Change static value without overriding dynamic value
- Add the new sections
- add the new keys

eg-

```
//copy of original with value changed ( key1 dynamic value)
$duplicateArray= [
    "section1" => [
      "key1" => [
        'dynamic'=>'aaa',
        'static'=>'v1',
       ],
    ],
];
```

```
//original updated with new value
$originalArray= [
    "section1" => [
      "key1" => [
        'dynamic'=>'a',
        'static'=>'v1 new',
       ],
      "key2" => [
        'dynamic'=>'b',
        'static'=>'v2',
       ],
    ],
    "section2" => [
      "key1" => [
        'dynamic'=>'c',
        'static'=>'v3',
       ],
    ]
];
```

Expected $duplicateArray -

```
$duplicateArray = [
   "section1" => [
      "key1" => [
        'dynamic'=>'aaa',
        'static'=>'v1 new',
       ],
      "key2" => [
        'dynamic'=>'b',
        'static'=>'v2',
       ],
    ],
    "section2" => [
      "key1" => [
        'dynamic'=>'c',
        'static'=>'v3',
       ],
    ]
];
```

Doing- $duplicateArray  = $duplicateArray + $originalArray added the new sections with the keys and contents

Answer (score 1):

I will provide a snippet that will work with your sample data.  It is not likely to be the most performant in terms of time complexity, but it is relatively concise in its ability to handle your 3-level data structure.

First recursively merge the original array into the duplicate array.  If there are any overlaps on static or dynamic values, then subarrays will be generated and no data will be lost. ([Demo of `array_merge_recursive()`](https://3v4l.org/aTHT6)) Then iterate the new structure and:

1. when a "dynamic" value conflict is encountered, use the first element's value (value from `$duplicateArray`)
2. when a "static" value conflict is encountered, use the second element's value (value from `$originalArray`)

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/CUB4W)) ([or Demo with key from ternary](https://3v4l.org/D3mFo))

```
$result = array_merge_recursive($duplicateArray,  $originalArray);
foreach ($result as &$keys) {
    foreach ($keys as &$types) {
        foreach ($types as $typeName => &$typeEntries) {
            if (is_array($typeEntries)) {
                $typeEntries = $typeEntries[(int) ($typeName !== 'dynamic')];
            }
        }
    }   
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'section1' => 
  array (
    'key1' => 
    array (
      'dynamic' => 'aaa',
      'static' => 'v1 new',
    ),
    'key2' => 
    array (
      'dynamic' => 'b',
      'static' => 'v2',
    ),
  ),
  'section2' => 
  array (
    'key1' => 
    array (
      'dynamic' => 'c',
      'static' => 'v3',
    ),
  ),
)
```

---

More performantly, save all of the duplicate array to the result, then only add data from the original array to the result array if the type name is "static" or there is no corresponding data at that position in the result array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/4EJDM))

```
$result = $duplicateArray;
foreach ($originalArray as $sectionName => $keys) {
    foreach ($keys as $keyName => $types) {
        foreach ($types as $typeName => $typeValue) {
            if ($typeName === 'static' || !isset($result[$sectionName][$keyName][$typeName])) {
                $result[$sectionName][$keyName][$typeName] = $typeValue;
            }
        }
    }   
}
var_export($result);
```

Comment: In the case of where the originalArray key changes in a section ie section1 - `key1` =>`key1234` , how can the duplication `key1` be changed to take the new value ?

Comment: Pleass show me a 3v4l.org demonstration of your new scenario so that I be confident of the advice that I give you.